# raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use WhatsApp via python following the below code, but I'm receiving the following error: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Is there something wrong with the code, or something that I'm missing here?
Could some one please help me here in fixing this and how do I send auto-reply using python scrips in WhatsApp.

Thank you for the help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Replace below path with the absolute path
# to chromedriver in your computer
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/saket/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)

# Replace 'Friend's Name' with the name of your friend 
# or the name of a group 
target = '"Friend\'s Name"'

# Replace the below string with your own message
string = "Message sent using Python!!!"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, x_arg)))
group_title.click()
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath)))
for i in range(100):
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I see only one element with mentioned attributes (`class="input", dir="auto", data-tab="1"`) and it's not `div`, but `input`... Could you try `inp_xpath = '//input[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'`? Also note that compound class name is `"input input-search"`, but not just `"input"`, so you should use `[contains(@class, "input")]` or `[@class="input-search"]`

Comment: here is the output after updating as mentioned above:
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
        selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platf

Comment: On which line you got it?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatsapp.py", line 25, in <module>
    group_title.click()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\ML\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click

Comment: self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\ML\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\ML\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in execute

Comment: self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\ML\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.2\python-3.4.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

Comment: the above 4 comments are the complete output that i got

Comment: Oh. Yep, my fault :) I thought you're trying to use search input... Are you sure you don't need to log in each time you run your script?

Comment: i dont think so

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that exception,

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
except TimeoutException:
    # You can write retry code here
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: File "whatsapp.py", line 13, in <module>
    browser.get(url)
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "whatsapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    except TimeoutException:
NameError: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined

Comment: Above is what i got after adding " try:
    browser.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    # You can write retry code here"

Comment: browser.get(url)
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined

Comment: Please check the updated answer. If you use separate function to connect to the sire using driver.get(), then you can make that function recursive in TimeoutException.

Comment: here is another error:                                                                                                  File "whatsapp.py", line 32, in <module>
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER)
NameError: name 'input_box' is not defined